# Datastructure for O(logn) deletion and index access in O(logn)

Tags: c++, data-structures

Please recommend a datastructure having O(logn) deletion and I want index of the element in the datastructure in O(1) or O(logn)??

Comment: Sounds like a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Deletion) or a heap, depending on what your index access needs to support

Comment: Why do you need to get the index? Many data structures don't have a meaningful index. Does the index have to stay the same?

Comment: By index, do you mean "get the nth element in sort order"?

Comment: cormen writes about augmented rb trees. I don't really get what you mean, but maybe you want to have a look.

Comment: Is your second requirement "find the nth element in O(log n) time" or "compute the distance from begin() to an arbitrary iterator in O(log n) time"?

Comment: @Yakk yes get the nth element in sorted order

Comment: @nbrooks how do you get the nth element in sorted order out of a heap in lg(n) time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most self balancing ordered binary trees can be modified to keep the number of children in each node, and maintaining that in lg(n) time per operation is pretty easy.

They clearly modify fewer than lg(n) nodes per operation, and in my experience the nodes they modify are often "vertically related".  It isn't free, but it tends not to be expensive.  <sup>1</sup>

Once you have that data in the nodes of the tree, finding the `n`th element is easy (if `n` is bigger then # in left subtree, subtract # in left subtree from `n` and recurse into right subtree, otherwise recurse into left subtree with unchanged `n`).

This would also work for non-binary self balancing trees, such as B-trees.

As far as I know, no `std` container supports random logarithmic delete, insert and index operations.  I looked for one a bit back.  I also did a quick check of boost, even looking at the multi-index containers, and couldn't figure out a way to get it to work.

*Footnotes:*

<sup>1</sup> When you modify a tree where you want the cost of getting the number of children of a node to be O(1) at the node, you have to modify nodes from your change all the way to the root.  There are at most lg(n) of them per modified node.  If the nodes are, however, "vertically related" to each other, the nodes you need to fix will be almost all the same on each node change.

On the other hand, suppose your tree rebalancing algorithm somehow managed to modify lg(n) utterly unrelated nodes, the cost would be as high as lg(n)*lg(n) to maintain the counts.